# Не запускается SwipeListView

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, android-studio, activity

Не запускается SwipeListView. (

Читал Гитхаб, менял идентификаторы, толку ноль, ругается на класс.

```
Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler: [swipe] C:\Users\Xaker\IdeaProjects\swipe\res\layout\main_activity.xml:7:  error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'swipeFrontView' in package 'com.example.swipe'

Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler: [swipe] C:\Users\Xaker\IdeaProjects\swipe\res\layout\main_activity.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'swipeBackView' in package 'com.example.swipe'

Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler: [swipe] C:\Users\Xaker\IdeaProjects\swipe\res\layout\main_activity.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'swipeDrawableChecked' in package 'com.example.swipe'

Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler: [swipe] C:\Users\Xaker\IdeaProjects\swipe\res\layout\main_activity.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'swipeDrawableUnchecked' in package 'com.example.swipe'

Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler: [swipe] C:\Users\Xaker\IdeaProjects\swipe\res\layout\main_activity.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList' in package 'com.example.swipe'

Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler: [swipe] C:\Users\Xaker\IdeaProjects\swipe\res\layout\main_activity.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'swipeMode' in package 'com.example.swipe'
```

Как быть-то? Говорит, что в моем пакете нет идентификатора, дак понятное дело, в нем нет, а как ему сказать, что он в `com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView`?

Может, тогда прокатит?

Comment: @Futurama, а откуда вообще берётся com.example.swipe?

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, com.example это мой проект. а swipeListView это библиотека.

     <LinearLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

Comment:      <com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
            android:id="@+id/example_swipe_lv_list"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
            swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
            swipe:swipeDrawableChecked="@drawable/choice_selected"
            swipe:swipeDrawableUnchecked="@drawable/choice_unselected"
            swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
            swipe:swipeMode="both"/>

      </LinearLayout>

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, Смысл тут в том, что XMLNS:SWIPE, вот этот SWIPE на бум написано, оттуда и вся проблема. Я туда написал asd

     а тут  

       swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"

Тоже написал asd: ошибка одна и та же. То есть сам компонент view не видит атрибуты, которые начинаются на swipe....

Comment: а как вы подключили библиотеку? как отдельный проект, или просто скопировали SwipeListView.java в ваш проект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно дать понять сборщику, что это за поля. Для этого в том месте, где у вас стили, разместите объявление поля контрола.

```
<declare-styleable name="SwipeListView">
    <attr name="swipeBackView" format="integer" />
    <attr name="swipeDrawableChecked" format="reference" />
    <attr name="swipeDrawableUnchecked" format="reference" />
    <attr name="swipeFrontView" format="integer" />
    <attr name="swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="swipeMode" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Насчет типов, не уверен, правильно ли я указал, но в целом идея такая.

Comment: Я решил проблему, незнаю почему может коряво как то получилось но.

Я всегда норм либы проекты чужие добавлял в видео библиотеки. А тту такое косяк. Раскидал все по папкам и все норм заработало, кому над на будущее.

Всем спасибо тема офф.

Answer (score 0):

[[@metalurgus](/users/3997/metalurgus)](/users/3997/metalurgus), как всегда, ProjectStructure->Modules->+->ImportModules->выбрал папку с исходниками, называется stimpleListView, потом далее раз 8 и все.
Добавил для SimpleListView nineon*******.jar, android-support_v41., а в моем проекте swipe -> ModuleDependency и там выбрал SimpleListVIew.

Я так всегда делаю.

Вот [статья](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/issues/78), кстати, попробовал через код - ничего не вышло.

А делал все по этой [статье](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/).

У него все получилось, у меня - нет.

Я писал в IDEA, а он в Eclipse.